# customize google maps javascript api 3 info window

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have three things I want to do to the infowindow.

1. How can change the "link" text in my info window to be an actual link.
2. How can I add an image to each infowindow
3. How can I adjust the size of the infowindow

Here is my javascript:

```js
<!--Google Maps Script-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initGmap() {

        var locations = [
            ["1 Severn", 45.489886, -73.595116, "link"],
            ["16 Grenville", 45.486391, -73.607096, "link"],
            ["17 Winchester", 45.477646, -73.603917, "link"],
            ["19 Winchester", 45.477607, -73.603962, "link"],
            ["52 Brookfield", 45.514604, -73.632722, "link"],
            ["317 Chemin du Golf", 45.467418, -73.548665, "link"],
            ["319 Chemin du Golf", 45.467418, -73.548665, "link"],
            ["447 Mt. Stephen", 45.483900, -73.600203, "link"],
            ["449 Mt. Stephen", 45.483933, -73.600179, "link"],
            ["603 Lansdowne", 45.484876, -73.609120, "link"],
            ["649 Belmont", 45.485654, -73.609270, "link"],
            ["652 Roslyn", 45.484788, -73.611407, "link"],
            ["1235 Bishop", 45.496458, -73.575373, "link"],
            ["1355 Scarboro", 45.523431, -73.639453, "link"],
            ["2184 De Cologne", 45.515823, -73.704550, "link"],
            ["2302 Brookfield", 45.514738, -73.632688, "link"],
            ["3013 De Breslay", 45.492288, -73.590195, "link"],
            ["3019 De Breslay", 45.492092, -73.590437, "link"],
            ["3021 Jean Girard", 45.493183, -73.590212, "link"],
            ["3025 De Breslay", 45.492075, -73.590771, "link"],
            ["4389 Decarie", 45.480705, -73.620274, "link"]
        ];

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 12,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.484876, -73.609120),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            scrollwheel: false
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var marker, i;

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                title: locations[i][0],
                map: map
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                return function () {
                    infowindow.setContent
                    ("<div class='map-address'>" + locations[i][0] + "</div> <div class='map-link'>" +
                    locations[i][3] + "</div>");
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));
        }
    }
</script>

<script async="" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDYbVG7Y7MqGw-OWkH2HW0RQlHtMO_bfoc&callback=initGmap"></script>
<!--End Google Maps Script-->
```

Comment: I don't think this deserves a downvote/close vote.

Comment: Where is the image path you want to add to the infowindow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that your images paths are also in your `locations` array like below:

```
var locations = [
    ["1 Severn", 45.489886, -73.595116, "link", "path/to/image.jpg"],
    ["16 Grenville", 45.486391, -73.607096, "link", "path/to/image.jpg"]
];
```

Now you can do the following in your marker click listener:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
    return function () {

        var html = '';

        // Create a container for the infowindow content
        html += '<div class="infowindow-content">';

        // Add a link
        html += '<a href="' + locations[i][3] + '">Text of your link</a>';

        // Add an image
        html += '<img src="' + locations[i][4] + '" />';

        // Close the container
        html += '</div>';

        infowindow.setContent(html);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
})(marker, i));
```

Now you have a container with class `.infowindow-content` that you can style with CSS. For example:

```
.infowindow-content {

    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

**Edit:** a working fiddle below

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/2a64m6xx/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks MrUpsidown. I am a beginner when it comes to Javascript. 
I am not sure if I am supposed to merge the above code into my current script or replace it completely. Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Sure. Check my edited answer. You can replace the marker listener with my code. The CSS part of course has to go in a .css file or as inline style. I will add a fiddle in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

In this part of your code,

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
    return function () {
        infowindow.setContent("<div class='map-address'>" + locations[i][0] + "</div> <div class='map-link'>" + locations[i][3] + "</div>");
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
})(marker, i));
```

specifically on your info.setContent(), perhaps you can just change

```
 "<div class='map-link'>"  +  locations[i][3] + "</div>"
```

to be

```
 "<a href='"+  locations[i][3] +"' class='map-link'> Some text </a>"
```

also you can append to it basic html

```
"<img src='"+ someImageURL +"' alt="AnImage">"
```

I hope this could help, if you have any other question let me know ;)

Comment: Bad use of `'` quotes and `"` double quotes.

Comment: Yeap my bad, I just wanted to give a fix to the problem without making things sound more complicated... By the way even if I make a bad usage this code still works... Anyways thanks for the feedback.

Comment: It would work, that's right. But it's always a good thing to give better code ;) Removing my downvote because you gave feedback.